# Using Nestjs to poll on DB Changes

Tags: nestjs

I am looking for an option to use nest as a back-end Gateway service -

The idea is to poll on DB changes ( and maybe later to move it to event driven ) - de facto no listener would be required here.
On change the Nest would update a 3rd pt API calls

What would be best practice here ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here, I'm doing something similar to what you're after: https://github.com/nerdybeast/sith-api/blob/feature/redis-cache/src/modules/api/sobjects/trace-flag/TraceFlagPoller.ts

I created a class that "polls" a backend and emits an event when it detects a change in that backend. You could have other code that listens for this event which makes the call to your 3rd party api.

UPDATE:

As you stated, Nest does have a basic application context which skips the http service setup, here's how you can do that:

index.ts

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { ApplicationModule } from './ApplicationModule';
import { DatabaseService } from './DatabaseService';

(async () => {

    const app = await NestFactory.createApplicationContext(ApplicationModule);
    const databaseService = app.get<DatabaseService>(DatabaseService);

    await databaseService.poll();
})();
```

DatabaseService.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class DatabaseService {

    private expectedResult: any;

    public async poll() : Promise<void> {

        const result = await getData();

        if(result !== this.expectedResult) {
            this.expectedResult = result;
            await axios.post('https://some-url.com', result);
        }

        //Poll every 5 seconds or whatever
        setTimeout(() => this.poll(), 5000);
    }
}
```

This could be the solution if you had to poll the database instead of being able to subscribe to it. With this approach, when you start the app, it will poll forever, constantly updating your 3rd party api.

I would start the `index.ts` file with `pm2` or `forever` so that you can have a graceful restart if your process crashes for some reason.

Comment: Thank you, The issue I see that Nest Natural behavior is based on a server listener to intercept incoming calls, In my case the backend actually have no API - it polls and update remote entities

Comment: Are you saying you need a process running that polls a db for changes and on those changes, makes calls to a 3rd party api? This process doesn't need to expose an api though?

Comment: Yes, A process that polls for DB changes - no Controller front end API is involved  -  For convenient ( same code structure ) I prefer it be based on NestJs, I guess it related to "Application context
" mentioned in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use typeORM subscribers like I have done many times for similar requirements. However I use an eventEmitter to not block the saving action. This is a snippet of what I usually do.

```js
@Injectable()
export class EntityUpdate implements EntitySubscriberInterface {
  constructor(
    @InjectConnection() readonly connection: Connection,
    @InjectEventManager() emitter: AppEvents<AbstractEntity>,
  ) { 
    connection.subscribers.push(this);
  }

  afterInsert(event: InsertEvent<AbstractEntity>): void {
    this.emitter('entity', {
      method: 'update',
      entity,
    });
  }
}
```

Then I could listen to the event anywhere within my application and handle that status change of the entity